# How do I run VBA code when none of the cells in a filtered table column are blank?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to run VBA code when all the cells in a filtered table column contain a value. I want a shape to be visible only when each cell in the column has a value, otherwise I want it to remain hidden.

I use the following code in Excel VBA:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("Table1[Verify]").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

Dim i As Range

For Each i In rng.Cells
    If i.Value <> "" Then
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("Oval 6").Visible = True
    ElseIf i.Value = "" Then
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("Oval 6").Visible = False
    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

The shape is hidden when the last cell in the column is blank, and visible when the last cell has a value. However, if all other cells are blank and the last cell is not, the shape remains visible.

In other words:
I want the shape visible when ALL of the xlCellTypeVisible cells are non-blank, and I want it hidden if ANY of them are blanks.

Comment: Can we restate the desired outcome? You want the shape visible when **ALL** of the `xlCellTypeVisible` cells are non-blank? But you want it hidden if **ANY** of them are blanks?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that the visibility only depends on the last cell is because you don't have an exit in your loop. If it finds a blank cell, it will still look at the next cell and hides or shows the shape based on the next value.

Basically you want to stop looking at the row the moment you hit a blank cell.

This means you need to use the `Exit For` statement:

```
ElseIf i.Value = "" Then
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Oval 6").Visible = False
    Exit For
End If
```

Comment: I made the switch, but now I am getting a "Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object'_Global' failed". Do you know what could be causing this?

Comment: Do you have any visible cells left? Do you get this error at `Set rng = `? Because if there are no visible cells left, it can't find the special cells and the range basically doesn't exist.

Comment: That is where I get the error, there are 20 visible cells in the range.

Comment: The error at least says that that particular range doesn't exist. Maybe `Range` is set to a different sheet. You can try to use `ActiveWorksheet.Range` for instance.

Comment: I found the problem. I had accidentally renamed the column header (causing the range to not exist) thanks!